# Python requests result missing part of web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to submit a form and download the resulting web page.  The problem is that the downloaded page is missing a large part of the page I see when I fill in the form on a browser.

I'm trying to view a seat map on aa.com. I get almost everything other than the actual seat map.

```
from requests import session

def get_page():
    payload = {
        'airportLookupRequired': 'true',
        'currentCodeForm': 'originAirport',
        'currentCalForm': 'viewSeatsForm',
        'flightNumber': '1132',
        'departureMonth': '9',
        'departureDay': '22',
        'originAirport': 'dfw',
        'destinationAirport': 'lga',
        'cabin': 'coach',
        '_button_submit': 'GO'
    }

    with session() as c:
        c.post('https://www.aa.com/seatmap/viewSeatsAccess.do', payload)
        r = c.get('https://www.aa.com/seatmap/viewSeatsSubmit.do')
        print r.content.replace('/content/images', 'https://www.aa.com/content/images')      

get_page()
```

Any suggestions for fixing this or figuring out why it's not working would be appreciated.

EDIT: using browser tools to look for AJAX requests, I see

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://www.aa.com/dwr/interface/SeatMapAjaxUtils.js". viewSeatsSubmit.do:52
```

Clicking on that leads to:

```
// Provide a default path to dwr.engine
if (dwr == null) var dwr = {};
if (dwr.engine == null) dwr.engine = {};
if (DWREngine == null) var DWREngine = dwr.engine;

if (SeatMapAjaxUtils == null) var SeatMapAjaxUtils = {};
SeatMapAjaxUtils._path = '/dwr';
SeatMapAjaxUtils.formatAmount = function(p0, p1, callback) {
  dwr.engine._execute(SeatMapAjaxUtils._path, 'SeatMapAjaxUtils', 'formatAmount', p0, p1, callback);
}
SeatMapAjaxUtils.getExitRowSeatSelectionResponse = function(p0, callback) {
  dwr.engine._execute(SeatMapAjaxUtils._path, 'SeatMapAjaxUtils', 'getExitRowSeatSelectionResponse', p0, callback);
}
```

which appears to be the code to generate the information I want. I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Your browser most likely executed some JavaScript code that loads the extra data over AJAX. Use your browser developer tools to see what AJAX requests are being made.

Comment: When I do that, I get links to 3 AJAX requests, such as https://www.aa.com/dwr/interface/SeatMapAjaxUtils.js  What do I do next?

Comment: Does anything look like JSON or HTML-formatted data you might be interested in? You might be able to call those endpoints *directly*.

Comment: Please see the additional information in my edited question. The two other AJAX links don't seem to be relevant.

Comment: You are misinterpreting a regular script resource for an AJAX request. In Chrome, select the network tab and filter on XHR requests only.

Comment: There are no XHR requests.

Comment: You'll have to analyse all resources that the browser *does* download then. Compare what the network tab shows is downloaded with what Python downloads to verify you are served the same information, and then analyze each resource in detail to see where the seat information is stored.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on how to do this? I have the feeling I'm missing something basic and obvious.

Comment: Not really, it's just common sense on how the web *works*. Browsers load resources from URLs and combine them in the browser, interpreting those resources. If that includes executable code (e.g. JavaScript) then the representation can change. JavaScript can request additional resources. How each page is represented can thus vary *wildly*. There is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: I realize there is no one-size-fits-all solution, but a walk through or three of other situations would help understand better how to approach this type problem.

Comment: @foosion there are plenty of resources online for doing this and a simple Google search should display them to you. It is not Martijn's responsibility to walk you through this in the comments here and it is not the appropriate place for that conversation either.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 I'm looking for a good tutorial, not Martijn walking through. I've found lots of online resources for submitting forms, but none that cover doing what Martjin suggested.  What search terms would be try to find how to analyze resources, deal with javascript requests, etc. The searches I've found have all returned rather simplistic results.

Comment: Aha. Analyzing resources proved to be a bit of a wild goose chase. The real problem was using both post and get requests. Eliminating the second one and fiddling a tiny bit led to the solution.